# NHWC vd NCHW outputs for ConvNets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, nnapi

[image]I have a probably dumb question. Should the outputs for NWHC and NCHW formats be the same for different layers in a convolutional neural network (e.g. depthwise conv2d, reg conv2d, pooling, etc.) - specifically when testing using vectors to represent input/output.

I understand that the indexing is different for the 2 formats, but the results should be the same, right?

Comment: What does "testing using vectors to represent input/output" mean?
BTW, yes.The output feature-map of a conv layer should be the same if the weights applied to the input tensor are the same and only the indexing is different.

Comment: when thinking about convnets, you probably think matrix of numbers. but when implementing, i am using vectors instead

Comment: @grizzleKat45 What do you mean by Matrix and vector in this context? How are you representing a NWHC tensor as a vector?

Comment: updated post. The colors represent the channels (RGB)